# No owner defined between domain classes: many to many relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm

These are my domain classes:

```
class Game {
    static hasMany = [players: User]
    static belongsTo = [owner: User]
}

class User {
    static hasMany = [games: Game]
}
```

If I try to use them as they are I get `No owner defined between domain classes`. So I need to set the owner of the relationship. Adding `static belongsTo = Game` to `User` causes `Domain classes cannot own each other in a many-to-many relationship`.

The only other option I can think of is to add `static belongsTo = User` to the `Game` class but I already have a `belongsTo` there.

How do I model this?

Answer (score 5):

```
class Game {
    User owner
    static hasMany = [players: User]
    static belongsTo = User
}

class User {
    static hasMany = [games: Game]
}
```

You will have to specify one side of the relationship, as the owner, by doing this you will make `User` domain class as the owner of the many to many relationship.

The `belongsTo` field controls where the dynamic `addTo*()` methods can be used
from. we’re able to call `User.addToGames()` because `Game` `belongsTo`
`User`. we can’t call `Game.addToPlayers()`.

Comment: i got the same data model and this doesnt work (ERROR MESSAGE: No owner defined between domain classes [class Game] and [class User] in a many-to-many relationship. Example: static belongsTo = User). your answer is just another gorm notation which means exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Game {
    User owner
    static hasMany = [players: User]
    static belongsTo = User
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it would be better not to use "belongsTo" at all? I mean using simple field reference like

```
class Game {
    User owner
    static hasMany = [players: User]
}
```

FYI,
I would be careful with using "owner" field name, it might cause problems when used somehow in a closure which has its own "owner" reference (e.g. in criteria builder) 
I know it caused problems back in grails 1.3.X, I don't know if it's still the case

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class Game {
    User owner
    static hasMany = [players: User]
    static belongsTo = User
}

class User {
    static hasMany = [games: Game, owns: Game]
    static mappedBy = [games:'players', owns: 'owner']
}
```

this settings work for me. And here is a good thread for mappedBy: [GORM mappedBy and mapping difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921242/gorm-mappedby-and-mapping-difference)