# GORM mappedBy and mapping difference

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In the GORM what is the difference between `mappedBy` and `mapping`?

```
static mapping = {
...
}

static mappedBy = {
...
}
```

Comment: Where have you seen this example?  The `mappedBy` value should be a map (square brackets), not a closure (curly braces).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**mapping**
`mapping` simply tells GORM to explicitly map one or more Domain properties to a specific database column.

```
class Person {
   String firstName

   static mapping = {
      table 'people'
      id column: 'person_id'
      firstName column: 'First_Name'
   }
}
```

in this case for instance I am instructing GORM to map the id attribute to the column `person_id` of the  `people` table and the `firstName` property to the `First_Name` column of the same table.

**mappedBy**
`mappedBy` instead let you control unidirectionality or bidirectionality of your classes associations. From [Grails documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html):

```
class Airport {
   static mappedBy = [outgoingFlights: 'departureAirport',
                   incomingFlights: 'destinationAirport']

   static hasMany = [outgoingFlights: Route,
                  incomingFlights: Route]
}

class Route {
    Airport departureAirport
    Airport destinationAirport
}
```

`Airport` defines two bidirectional one-to-many associations. If you don't specify `mappedBy` you would get an error because GORM cannot infer which of the two properties on the other end of the association (either `departureAirport` or `destinationAirport`) each one-to-many should be associated with.

[image]

In other words it helps you remove the ambiguity that comes from bidirectional associations.

Comment: Even further, when you have a two one to one relationships in GORM, it will actually use the first association to put his foreign key. The first is determined by the lexicographic order of the variable names of the corresponding type. So you have to use `mappedBy`. If you don't want an association update on the other side, you can set `mappedBy = [outgoingFlights: 'none']`